# Access viewController property

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using this function:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return viewController.ident; // this doesn't work: property 'ident' not found
}
```

In this function there are getting passed `viewControllers` from different types so: vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, ... and they all have a '`ident`' property and inherit from `UIViewController`. How can I access this property?

Comment: there are ways to do it, but you should also consider a structural change to make all those viewcontrollers having a 'ident' property to subclass from the same superclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `viewController` to the Class which has the `ident` property. Or do it by using `valueForKey` like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return [[viewController valueForKey:@"ident"] integerValue]; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this line of code:

```
return [viewController performSelector:@selector(ident)];
```